# unexpected token '$' in pymongo program

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

```
bdnome = collection.find_one({ $text: {$search: vername}})
```

At this line a error appears in "$text" with the following error

```
"unexpected token '$'" and "unexpected toke 'text', and a error
appears in "$search" --- "unexpected token '{'" and "unexpected
token '$'" and "unexpected token 'search'", and a error occurs
as well in "vername" --- "unexpected token 'vername".
```

I'm working with databases in MongoDB

Comment: Is this Python code or Mongo Shell? Please post the entire error message within a `<pre></pre>` tag in your question.

Comment: Try wrap in qoutes `collection.find_one({ "$text": {"$search": vername}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use JavaScript syntax in Python. That doesn't work.

```
bdnome = collection.find_one({ "$text": {"$search": vername}})
```